# Which app uses my GPS

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, battery, gps

I have discovered battery drain and it is caused by GPS but I don't understand how is that possible when my location is turned off and location permission is denied for every app installed and also any app I use don't need gps. I don't have any unfamous or pirated apps installed, and didn't get any new apps since 5 days, and problem started today. So is there any way to see which app is using gps since here is just blank name..?
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whatever have happened here it is solved by rebooting phone (d'oh). I hate this way of solving bugs on R2D2's.

Answer (score 2):

Go to setting--> Location

Then you will see list of recent apps who requested location.
If you are still seeing apps there who is using location service then you can find which app is using your location service .

Comment: Nothing special here only google play services "low battery use"

Answer (score 0):

May be Google Play Services is the culprit here. It drains a battery a lot, infact it uses wifi scan in the background too!. So turning permissions off for it might help with the battery drain.

Comment: I turned off all location permissions, however you can't turn off permission for play services since it's location provider, you can turn off location what I did, and it didn't helped. Also I turned off wifi and bluetooth scanning.

Answer (score -1):

In the settings you can go to apps and there should be a menu where you can see which app has which permission, there you can click on location and you will see.
Sincerely
Rikvola

Comment: There is 14 apps that have permission but as I said none of them have it granted..

Comment: Now i have a good solution:
root your phone and don't install any google stuff. It will use your battery as well but not that much. This is always on for the system it isn't used by any apps. 

And probably some apps have a "hack" to overrule the permissions.